# How to concatenate two csv files in python

Tags: python, concatenation

I have a code in which I have tried to merge several csv files using pd.concat(),
the issue I have is that the concatenated file has the last column of file1.csv and the first column of file2.csv merged in a single cell (and same for file.csv and file3.csv) as illustrated below. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

```
file1 = 'file1.csv'
file2 = 'file2.csv'
file3 = 'file3.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv( file1, sep="\n" ,na_values='NA')
df2 = pd.read_csv( file2, sep="\n" ,na_values='NA')
df3 = pd.read_csv( file3, sep="\n" ,na_values='NA')
BigDf = pd.concat([df1, df2,df3], axis=1)
BigDf.to_csv('final.csv', sep="\t", index = False)
```

eg. file1.csv is

```
       A      B      C      
0  False  False  False  
1   True   True  False   
2  False  False  False   
3  False  False  False
```

file2.csv is

```
      D     E      F     
0  False  False  False  
1   True   True  False   
2  False  False  False   
3  False  False  False
```

the merged file should be

```
       A      B      C      D     E     F     
0  False  False  False    False  False  False 
1  True   True  False     True   True  False
2  False  False  False    False  False  False 
3  False  False  False    False  False  False
```

instead it is

```
       A      B      CD     E     F     
0  False  False  FalseFalse  False  False 
1  True   True   FalseTrue   True  False
2  False  False  FalseFalse  False  False 
3  False  False  FalseFalse  False  False
```

Comment: Umm. The structure you want does not seem to be best obtained by Concat. How about pd.merge() instead?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @SreeramTP the expected result should be the files merged and each column should be separate. like the third illustration shown above but for some reason I keep getting the C and D list in the same column as shown in the 4th illustration

Comment: can you check my answer to see is that your expected result

Comment: @SreeramTP Thank you. But is there a way where I do not have to write the header of the columns since the actual file I am working on has 10 columns for each csv and specifying the column names in the end can be tedious.  i mean here df_new_loaded.columns
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')

Comment: with ```df_new_loaded.columns``` I was just checking the column names in the data frame. If you don't want to write column name to the csv file do ```df_new.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False, sep='\t')```

Comment: @SreeramTP it doesn't seem to be working and i get the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

concat is working as expected for me, see the code below,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
df1
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False

df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
df2
       D      E      F
0  False  False  False
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1   True   True  False   True   True  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False

df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df_new
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1   True   True  False   True   True  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False

df_new.to_csv("test.csv", sep='\t', index=False)

df_new_loaded = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep='\t')
df_new_loaded
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1   True   True  False   True   True  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False

df_new_loaded.columns
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')

df_new_loaded
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1   True   True  False   True   True  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='col')
```

But it may give you the same result